# (HTML & CSS) Transparent Nav Bar on homepage only. Black background-color in other views

Tags: html, css, sass

I am fairly new to CSS and have run into a problem. I have a horizontal (Bourbon Refills) navigation bar in my application. On my homepage the navbar is semi-transparent with the background image showing through. I would like for the navbar to be a different color in all of the other views (for example the backgound color should be black in all views except for the homepage) but am unsure how to do this aside from having two separate navbars.  Surely there is a better solution.  (Right now I am placing the navbar in my index.html.erb file as a partial `<%= render 'partials/navbar' %>`.) Any help would be appreciated!

navbar.scss:

```
  header.navigation {
  $base-border-color: gainsboro !default;
  $base-border-radius: 3px !default;
  $action-color: #477DCA !default;
  $dark-gray: #333 !default;
  $large-screen: 53.75em !default;
  $navigation-padding: 1em;
  $navigation-background: transparent;
  $navigation-color: white;
  $navigation-color-hover: transparentize(white, 0.2);
  $navigation-height: 70px;
  $navigation-nav-button-background: $action-color;
  $navigation-nav-button-background-hover: lighten($navigation-background, 10%);
  $navigation-nav-button-border: 1px solid lighten($navigation-nav-button-background, 20%);
  $navigation-active-link-color: transparentize(white, 0.5);
  $horizontal-bar-mode: $large-screen;

  background-color: $navigation-background;
  min-height: $navigation-height;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

  .navigation-wrapper {
    @include clearfix;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
  }
```

_navbar.html.erb:

```
  <header class="navigation" role="banner">
    <div class="navigation-wrapper">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="logo">
      <!--<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/placeholder_square.png" alt="Logo Image">
      </a>-->
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navigation-menu-button" id="js-mobile-menu">MENU</a>
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul id="js-navigation-menu" class="navigation-menu">
          <li class="nav-link"><%= link_to 'Camelot Chess', root_path %></li>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="nav-link"><%= link_to 'Create Game', new_game_path %></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><%= link_to 'Join Game', games_path %></li>
          <li class="nav-link right"><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
          <li class="nav-link right">Hello, <%= current_user.email %></li>
          <% else %>
          <li class="nav-link right"><%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li class="nav-link right"><%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class on the `.navigation-wrapper` and change the background color only when that class is on the nav.

```
.navigation-wrapper.black {
    background-color: black;
}
```

You can use some conditional to add the class on the nav only if you aren't on the homepage.

Edit:

In the controller as instance variable such as `@black_header = true` and then in your .erb file do

```
<header class="navigation-wrapper <%= @black_header? + 'black' : '' %>" " role="banner"
```

If all of your pages will have the black header except the homepage, then you actually might want to do the opposite here.  (Use the instance variable for when you don't want a black header, and default it to black)

Comment: Thanks for your response Samantha.  I have used conditionals to make things work with other browsers, but am not sure how to use them to work on specific pages.  How would I do that in this case?

Comment: Awesome!  That worked.  Thank you.  I will point out that you're above answer had a syntax error and (in my case) the conditional needed to be added to the navigation-wrapper class like so: `<header class="navigation-wrapper <%= @black_header? + 'black' : '' %>" " role="banner">`